# Get Image Dimensions of Hidden Carousel Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

ON my website, I need to apply css margins to certain images in a Bootstrap carousel.  I iterate over images on the page and run the javascript function applyImageRotation when a particular image needs to be rotated.  I tried to ensure that the image was fully loaded on the page before attempting to apply the margins:

```
function applyImageRotation(carousel_img, thumbnail_img, rotation, pageSource){
  if(pageSource=="index"){
     carousel_img.on('load', function(){
        console.log('carousel_img dimensions: ' + carousel_img.width() + ' ' + carousel_img.height());
        setCarouselImageMargins($(this), carousel_width);
     });
});
```

However, when I actually try to run the code, it seems like it doesn't get the correct image width, I believe potentially because the image is not the active one in the bootstrap carousel.

```
carousel_img dimensions: 0 381
```

When I run the same commands after the page has loaded, I get that the image width is non-zero.

**How can I get the dimensions of an image that is not active in a bootstrap carousel?**

Comment: Although Adam's solution is probably the way to go, if you need to change the dimensions on demand, bootstrap emits an event you can hook onto. See line 117 for the name and event object it passes. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because you're getting the dimensions of the element that is in the DOM and the initial carousel stylings at the time you are running this function are probably affecting that.

I would do something like this:

```
function applyImageRotation(carousel_img, thumbnail_img, rotation, pageSource){
  if(pageSource=="index"){
     $('<img/>')
          .on('load',function() {
            console.log('carousel_img dimensions: ' + this.width + ' ' + this.height);
            setCarouselImageMargins(carousel_img, carousel_width);
          })
          .attr('src',carousel_img[0].src);
  }
});
```

The good part about it is that it won't actually request your image twice, it will just pull it from the cache. Or if it's not yet in the cache, it will make the request to get it and the  element in the document will end up loading the image from the cache.

Full disclosure, of course, this method does generate a small amount of garbage that will be collected though, by creating a detached DOM tree (img element) for each carousel image.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!  this worked for me, although I don't understand fully how it works.  can you explain what $('<img/') is doing?

Comment: `$('<img/>')` is creating a new img element, setting it's src to be the same as the src of `carousel_img` and then attaching a load event listener to it. The img element created by `$('<img/>')` is not in the DOM anywhere and therefore not influenced by any CSS styles.

Comment: got it! thanks again for your helpful solution and explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you can run your function after the document is ready.

```
$(function(){
    //put your function here
}
```

$(function() is a shortcut for document.on("ready")

Answer (score -1):

Give the image time to fully load into the document.

I've been able to overcome this issue by using `setTimeout`.

I'm not familiar with Csarosuel; however, try this.

```
function applyImageRotation(carousel_img, thumbnail_img, rotation, pageSource){
  if(pageSource=="index"){
     carousel_img.on('load', function(){

setTimeout(function(){

        console.log('carousel_img dimensions: ' + carousel_img.width() + ' ' + carousel_img.height());
        setCarouselImageMargins($(this), carousel_width);

},500);
     });
});
```

Comment: Arbitrary timeout durations are hardly a solution and will not work 100% of the time.

Comment: That's so odd Adam because it works 100% all the time in every browser. This is an absolute fact!

Comment: try and do it on a high latency connection and it won't. Not to mention with this "solution" your forcing the user to wait 500ms when, if you were to do it properly, it may take much less than that.

Comment: What about a 10 megapixel image on a dial up connection? :)

Comment: Adam, you're grasping for straws. You should not have -1 me. I'll be honest who in the hell develops with dial-up connects in mind?